# Can I wait all the promise until it resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, promise

I have a nodejs app which fetch data from different api and I want to aggregate the data from different api and then send it out. However I can only resolve the promise of api data fetching but the res.send only sending empty array. I am guessing the res.send didn't wait for the json() function to resolve and already sent out the data. How can I resolve this problem?

```
app.get('/:keyword',(req,res)=>{
    let unsplashPromise = unsplash.search.photos(......)
    let pixabayPromise = fetch(......)
    let jsonPromise
    let data = []

    Promise.all([unsplashPromise, pixabayPromise]).then(files=>{
        files.map((promise)=>{
            if(promise.url.includes("unsplash")){
                promise.json().then((photos)=>{
                    photos.results.map((photo)=>{
                        data.push({
                            image_ID: photo.id,
                            thumbnails: photo.urls.thumb,
                            preview: photo.urls.regular,
                            title: photo.alt_description,
                            source: "unsplash",
                            tags: photo.tags
                        })
                    })
                })

            }else if(promise.url.includes("pixabay")){
                promise.json().then((json)=>{
                    json.hits.map((photo)=>{
                        data.push({
                            image_ID: photo.id,
                            thumbnails: photo.previewURL,
                            preview: photo.largeImageURL,
                            title: null,
                            source: "pixabay",
                            tags: photo.tags
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
            return data
        })
    }).then(()=>{
        res.send(data)
    })


})
```

Comment: `Promise.all(/* your promises */).then(/* your handling of those*/).then(data => res.send(data))`

Comment: You've done `Promise.all(...).then(...)` once. You need to do it for **every group of promises**.

Comment: @VLAZ I tried your double then method but it did not work

Comment: @miketsui3a did you `return data`?

Comment: @VLAZ do you mean ```Promise.all([x,y]).then(files=>{......return data}) ?

Comment: Yes. The *next* `.then` handler receives the data that is returned from the previous one. So, if you don't return anything, then the next one receives `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ I added that return data but still receiving empty data

Comment: @VLAZ I update the code in the question, now my code is looking like this.

Comment: There are promises in the `files.map` that need to be waited for as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it waits for nested promises.

```js
app.get('/:keyword',(req,res)=>{
    let unsplashPromise = unsplash.search.photos(somthineg)
    let pixabayPromise = fetch(`somthing`)

    let data = []

    Promise.all([unsplashPromise, pixabayPromise]).then(files=>
        Promise.all(files.map((promise)=>{
            if(promise.url.includes("unsplash")){
                return promise.json().then((photos)=>{
                    photos.results.map((photo)=>{
                        data.push({
                            image_ID: photo.id,
                            thumbnails: photo.urls.thumb,
                            preview: photo.urls.regular,
                            title: photo.alt_description,
                            source: "unsplash",
                            tags: photo.tags
                        })
                    })
                })

            }
            if(promise.url.includes("pixabay")){
                return promise.json().then((json)=>{
                    json.hits.map((photo)=>{
                        data.push({
                            image_ID: photo.id,
                            thumbnails: photo.previewURL,
                            preview: photo.largeImageURL,
                            title: null,
                            source: "pixabay",
                            tags: photo.tags
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
            return Promise.resolve();
        }))
    ).then(() => {
        res.send(data);
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

Comment: tried but dosen't work

Comment: in the 1st `then` where you have `promise.json().then`, you need to wait for them too.
the easiest way would be to add `async` to your function and then to add `await promise.json().then`. In that case `.then` with `send` will be executed once the data has been collected.

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer.

Comment: is that a way to catch error from different promise 1 by 1? let say my first api fetch failed but can still get the data of second api fetch

Comment: you can add a `.catch` before `.then` and to set a flag whether you want to skip the request.
when you want to check every promise in `Promise.all` simply add `.catch()` to everyone and map the result to an empty array. then you don't have the error anymore and failed promises will return an empty array.

Comment: @ satanTime I am not quite sure what you mean. Did you mean that i can add something like Promise.all([unsplashPromise.catch(err=>{}), pixabayPromise.catch(err=>{})]) ?

Comment: exactly, you are right :)

Answer (score -2):

You can add 2 flags, one for `unsplash` and the other for `pixabay` and once both are true then you can send the response. e.g.

> ```
> app.get('/:keyword',(req,res)=>{
> let unsplashPromise = unsplash.search.photos(somthineg)
> let pixabayPromise = fetch(`somthing`)
> let unsplashPromiseDone, pixabayPromiseDone = false;
>
> let data = []
>
> Promise.all([unsplashPromise, pixabayPromise]).then(files=>{
>     files.map((promise)=>{
>         if(promise.url.includes("unsplash")){
>             promise.json().then((photos)=>{
>                 photos.results.map((photo)=>{
>                     data.push({
>                         image_ID: photo.id,
>                         thumbnails: photo.urls.thumb,
>                         preview: photo.urls.regular,
>                         title: photo.alt_description,
>                         source: "unsplash",
>                         tags: photo.tags
>                     })
>                 })
>                 unsplashPromiseDone = true;
>             })
>
>         }else if(promise.url.includes("pixabay")){
>             promise.json().then((json)=>{
>                 json.hits.map((photo)=>{
>                     data.push({
>                         image_ID: photo.id,
>                         thumbnails: photo.previewURL,
>                         preview: photo.largeImageURL,
>                         title: null,
>                         source: "pixabay",
>                         tags: photo.tags
>                     })
>                 })
>             pixabayPromiseDone = true;
>             })
>         }
>         if (unsplashPromiseDone && pixabayPromiseDone) {
>             res.send(data)
>         }
>     })
> }).catch(err=>{
>     console.log(err)
> })
> ```
>
> })

Comment: The `files.map` loop can finish before the inner promises resolve and the flags are set.